# Some mobile devices can't detect the image from the firebase database

Tags: image, ionic3

I have an ionic v3 app using firebase database, showing some external link images and text in the app.

This app has been published for three years, until recently I update some contnet for this app then something went wrong.

Some of the users mobile can't detect the image from the firebase database and shown the default image instead.(I use the image-loader plugin which can set default image). 
The text are displayed correctly, but the images are not shown.

My android and iphone is working fine, images and text shown correctly.

I don't know what's wrong? Somebody helps!!

Comment: What is your image extension?

Comment: all are jpg file